# Calculating the Time complexity using Radix sort

Tags: sorting, radix-sort

Im trying to determine what is the time complexity of sorting numbers with a specific range and base.
I have n numbers in the range of 1-n^10 and the base for the radix sort is n/log n.
I have tried to calculate it using log equations but im getting to a linear result, I dont know wether im right or wrong.
Thank you very much.

Comment: What are your thoughts?  How have you tried to analyze its running time complexity?

Comment: @D.W. i tried to convert n^10 to n/log n base using the formula: (n/log n)^d = n^10 and then using log on both sides: d*log(n/log n) = 10 log(n) => d = 10 log n/ (log (n/logn)) and then the time complexity of the radix sort is: d(n+k) => using the d that i found i think its linear

Comment: Welcome to COMPUTER **SCIENCE** @SE. Do not comment comments: edit your question; you can use $L^AT_EX$ for formulas (in comments, too).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct.  We have $(n/\log n)^{20} \le n^{10}$ for all $n\ge 1$, so each number can be expressed using at most $d=20$ "digits".  The running time of radix sort is $O(dn)$, and $O(20n)$ is $O(n)$, so the running time is linear in $n$.